# Move theme layout elements on a product view from within a Module Magento 2

Tags: product, magento2.2, product-page, page-layouts

I am having trouble moving the short description on the `product page`. I tried with the `move` command within the `layout file` without any luck. I can move any new created `block` where I want but I can't modify theme declared `layout blocks`.

Location of my `layout xml` file

> Vendor/Module/view/frontend/layout/catalog_product_view.xml

Layout file code

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>

        <referenceContainer name="content">
            <block class="Test\Catalog\Block\Rewrite\Product\View" name="product.seller.list" template="test.phtml" />
        </referenceContainer>

        <!--This works as created above-->
        <move element="product.seller.list" destination="product.info.main" after="product.info.review"/> 

        <!--This does not work-->
        <move element="product.info.overview" destination="product.info.main" after="-"/>

    </body>
</page>
```

If I modify the theme layout file the move works. Any help will be great

Answer (score 0):

`product.info.overview` is generally the last element of the `product.info.main` component. When you use `after="-"` you're making if the last element of the `product.info.main` component. I would try using `before="-"` so that it becomes the first element in that component or so you can at least see it move. Then you can specify where you want it based on the M2 dev docs for layout updates (https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/frontend-dev-guide/layouts/xml-instructions.html#fedg_layout_xml-instruc_ex_mv).

Also, if you're not seeing changes you may need to clear your layout cache or recompile `php bin/magento cache:flush layout` or `php bin/magento setup:di:compile`.

Comment: That is correct, normally it is at the bottom however the theme we are using they moved it to the top and I would like to move it to the bottom.I tried the above and it is not working. I can move my element however not the ```product.info.overview```

Comment: I can however move the ```product.info.overview``` when I extend the theme file however I would like to do this from my module

Comment: Gotcha, that makes more sense. I believe that you’ll need to create a theme to go with your module and activate that theme. Because your other theme is active is not going to look at any of the layout files in your module.

Comment: So you are saying there is no way to move an element from the module? just to make sure I understand

Comment: If you want to override as opposed to extend the path to the file needs to be different. It should be setup like this `<theme_dir>/<Namespace_Module>/layout/override/theme/<Parent_Vendor>/<parent_theme>/catalog_product_view.xml`. Generally, the approach is to extend, but in your case you can override the base xml with this approach and not have to create a theme to override the parent theme. More details on overriding a layout file here: https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/frontend-dev-guide/layouts/layout-override.html

Comment: yea, but I would like it to be friendly to different themes so overriding might not be the option. Thanks anyway

Comment: Overriding or extending are the two ways to move layout files. If those aren't acceptable you could look into a CSS based solution and use something like flex with the order property and target the default Magento classes to specify the order of items on the product detail page.

Comment: Yes that is possible with CSS and override but I wanted to extend just make it better. But I guess extend doesn't work to move elements from a module.